# Shopify failed transaction returns successful one

Tags: shopify

I am currently integrating new payment gateway on Shopify, I able to process successful transaction through sending the response result as completed but the issue I'm encountering now, everytime I return failed result as my response on Shopify still it will return successful transaction but then the order is not added on the admin order listings.The order no is different, it is displaying the reference no instead of the order no.

Comment: are you sure you're not confused about "checkouts" and "orders" ? Those are diferent concepts but they're very tied. If you try to elaborate a bit more your question we might be able to help. Starting with "I'm integrating a new payment gateway" is confusing as no one integrates payment gateways directly with Shopify except for the offsite ones. All the rest, rely on Active Merchant.

Comment: Hi alexandra, thank you for taking time to reply on these. I'm currently working on a Payment service provider and trying to integrate it on shopify shop for our merchants.And I'm not confused with checkouts and orders, as I was referring on the orders that is listed on the admin side.If I process successful transaction,it appears on the order list of Shopify unlike with failed transaction.

Comment: Which type of payment gateway are you trying to integrate with Shopify? Are you aware about Active Merchant?